# Show derivative of integral equals integral of partial derivative if M[0,1]-measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to determine a method of approaching the following:

Suppose that $f:[0,1] \times (0,1)$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ is such that, for each $y \in (0,1)$, the function $f^{[y]}(x) = f(x,y)$ is $\mathcal{M}_{[0,1]}$-measurable.  Further suppose that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exists and is bounded on $[0,1] \times (0,1)$.

Show that $$\frac{d}{dy}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y) dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)dx$$.

I assume that the Lebesgue-$[0,1]$ notation means that it is Lebesgue measurable over $[0,1]$.  I am pretty sure that I need to use the DCT, but how do I go about doing so with this?  Do I just make some arbitrary function and claim that it bounds this rectangle?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal M_{[0,1]}$-measurable?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this website: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf. You can find your answer in introdunction section, equation (1.2).